# Bypass workflow steps for administrator in Kentico

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I have created a workflow which lets Admin publish document.
It's a basic workflow.

What I want is to bypass process for Admin, currently what is happening is that Administrator have to create/approve/publish , Administrator can publish changes directly by not following these steps.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Having looked at the workflow module I dont think it is possible. you could give admins full rights to create, approve and publish their content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have done it by adding this condition.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using basic workflow. You can do it either by using advanced workflow (since v7) or by customizing EditMenu.ascx.cs (and underlying classes) + probably CMSDocumentManager. If you want to use workflow just for versioning purposes, use "Automatically publish changes" option on 'General' tab of basic workflow.